# <a> restoration of stolen property; <a> restoration of the law

Tags: articles

three examples from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/restoration):
**(1a)** ***a** restoration of stolen property*
**(1b)** *restoration of stolen property*
**(2a)** *The town called for **a** restoration of the law*.
my versions:
**(2b)** *The town called for restoration of the law*.
**(2c)** *The town called for **the** restoration of the law*.

I don't understand what function the indefinite article "a" in (1a) and (2a) has, i.e. what "a" means there.

What's the difference between (1a) and (1b)?
What's the difference between (2a), (2b) and (2c)?

Comment: It doesn't really "mean" anything whether you use the definite, indefinite, or zero article in many contexts involving abstract nouns like this. But some combinations just don't work very well. You can call for ***the abolition*** of slavery, and more rarely just call for ***abolition*** of slavery with no article, but it would be *very* strange to call for ***an abolition*** of slavery. On the other hand, there's nothing unusual about [calling for ***an end*** to slavery](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calling+for+an+end+to+slavery%22), so there's no fixed logical rule involved.